# How do I use Previous function in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm working on SSRS report.

There are two main fields `CurrentMV` and `PreviousMV`
both are having there different formulas but I need to change field `PreviousMV` to take a value of `CurrentMV` but `previous date` value I'm trying using `Previous` function of SSRS

please help me.

field `CurrentMV` having expression like `=Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value)`
[image]

Comment: You say you're using `Sum`... So those are group header/footer rows?

Comment: What have got there at the moment? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
=Previous(Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value))
```

Or

```
=Previous(Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value, "Detail"), "Detail")
```

[More reading](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms156372%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).